# Android(Java) - How can I do a async loading of linked list

Tags: java, android, linked-list, scrollview, android-asynctask

I have linked list of objects and I want to make an asynchronous loading for list to listView, what is more, I must load by 10 (or 20, for example) elements, depending on the scroll position. So, please, help me to do this task.

I'm beginner and I'm very sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

Comment: Thanks. But... It's an easier way?

Comment: Easier than what? It's pretty simple, all hard work has been done for you by CommonsWare, you need only specify the way to obtain every portion of elements plus the pending view.